# Case Approval Process - Add users dynamically via APEX

Tags: salesforce, apex

I need a way to add users to the Approval Process via a trigger because users selected to approve will be based off of criteria set on the record.  This results in having several combinations and goes over the limit of the approver process.   I am capturing these combinations in a custom setting.

So far, I have a custom setting, custom button that calls a webservice.  Based on location and client, I pull the users.  These are the users I need to add to the approval process that I have submitted.  Here is my code:

```
    Case cInfo = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Carrier__c, Client__c, Shipper__c FROM Case  where Id =: CaseId];

    Account sInfo = [SELECT Id, Location__c FROM Account where Id =: cInfo.Shipper__c];

    string Client = cInfo.Client__c;
    string Location = sInfo.Location__c;

    if(Client != null && Location != null){

    try{
        list<Automate_Approval_Routing__c> aList = [Select Email_Address__c, UserId__c from Automate_Approval_Routing__c Where Location__c =: Location and Client__c =: Client];
        if(aList.IsEmpty()==false){

            Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
            req1.setComments('Submitting request for approval.');
            req1.setObjectId(cInfo.id);
            Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req1);

            List<Id> newWorkItemIds = result.getNewWorkitemIds();
            List<ProcessInstanceHistory> hist = new List<ProcessInstanceHistory>();
            List<ProcessInstanceWorkItem> work = new List<ProcessInstanceWorkItem>();
            // Instantiate the new ProcessWorkitemRequest object and populate it

            Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req2 = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
            req2.setComments('Approving request.');
            req2.setAction('Approve');
            req2.setNextApproverIds(new Id[] {UserInfo.getUserId()});

            // Use the ID from the newly created item to specify the item to be worked

            req2.setWorkitemId(newWorkItemIds.get(0));

            List<ProcessInstance> processInstances = [select Id, Status from ProcessInstance where TargetObjectId = :CaseId];                

            for(Automate_Approval_Routing__c aa : aList){

                ProcessInstanceWorkItem newPiwi= new ProcessInstanceWorkItem();
                newPiwi.ProcessInstanceId = processInstances[0].Id;
                newPiwi.OriginalActorId = aa.UserId__c;
                work.add(newPiwi);

                ProcessInstanceHistory phi = new ProcessInstanceHistory();
                //phi.OriginalActorId = aa.UserId__c;
                phi.IsPending = true;
                phi.processInstances[0].Id;
                phi.RemindersSent = 0;
                phi.StepStatus = 'Pending';
                phi.TargetObjectId = CaseId;

                hist.add(phi);

            }


                if(work.IsEmpty()==false){
                    database.insert(work);
                }

        }







    }catch (exception ex){
        return ex.getMessage() + ' ' + ex.getLineNumber();
    }
        return null;
    }else{
        return 'Information is missing and Claim can not be submitted for Approval';
    }
```

Comment: You've not indicated what the error or issue is. Please remember to ask a question that fits within Stack Overflow's scope (see [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the FAQ)

Comment: How do I add users to the approval process via APEX?